# Mysterious Cartesian product in Oracle UPDATE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

We have a unique problem in production. Every now and then our Oracle 12c database will hang during our batch cycle in the middle of the night. We will have to restart the database to keep going for a few days/weeks. Then it happens again.
After some digging, we have narrowed it down to this SQL:

```
UPDATE c_bill SET reason_desc = (SELECT description FROM codes 
WHERE code_group = 'TRANSACTION_TYPE' AND code = c_bill.reason_code);
```

I've renamed the tables - but the codes table have code and description. The developer is trying to copy description from this to the c_bill table.

This SQL is part of a stored procedure that's run nightly as part of a batch job. The developer does another update just before this, that passes through fine, but this SQL takes a long time.

During a particular run, the table had 36308 rows. When I check the Production DB (I look at the SQLs in v$sql table), I see the following:

Rows_processed for the 1st update 36308
Rows_processed for the above update 1318270864, and that happpens to be = 36308 * 36308!! (Cartesian product?)

We do not have this problem in TEST. When I tried the UPDATE and explain planned it in TEST, no problem - it shows exactly 36308 rows in both UPDATE and v$sql.

This is puzzling. Does anyone see a chance of a cartesian product in that SQL? Or are you aware of any bug in Oracle 12c optimizer that might turn it into a Cartesian product (We just applied some patches to fix bugs with Group by!).

I have fair amount of experience with Oracle - i tune queries here. I've suggested to the developer to add a where condition to be sure. We are yet to test that. In the mean time, I wanted to pass by the Oracle experts to get your take on it. Any comments/suggestions much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** for anyone looking at this post in the future -
The problem is not Cartesian product, but the problem UPDATE sql running in a cursor loop on th same table, hence looking like Cartesian. See Justin's answer.

Comment: Is `executions` in `v$sql` 1?  Or is that 36308 (i.e. the statement updated 36308 rows in each of 36308 executions)?  Can you get the query plan for the statement (either from the shared pool or from AWR/ Statspack) to see whether it actually has a Cartesian product?  Does `c_bill` have columns named `code_group` or `code` or do those only exist in `codes`?

Comment: I think you may have nailed it! Executions = 36308 and yes the procedure it is in, has a cursor that picks up rows for keys in the c_bill table. The previous update I mentioned about, actually had the keys used in the cursor SQL, but this one didn't. I will do some more testing and post back. I am not a DBA, I will check the AWR stats next week (they are gone for long w/e now!). Can you please post it back as an answer?

Comment: From the v$sql again, last_load_time for the problem UPDATE statement was the last_load_time was 2016-09-02/03:04:02
and the last_active_time was 09/02/2016 4:48. Does this mean the same SQL kept running 36308 times during that hour??

Comment: That means it was executed 36308 times during the hour, yes.

Comment: @Justin, Then that must be the reason for 36308*36308. This procedure has been hanging our prod db randomly for a while. Incidentally, there were some patches that went in for that y'day. And today, they asked me to take a look. Since this SQL came up as the top activity constantly, I tried to analyze it. Now, looking at the cursor loop in the procedure, I see this UPDATE would have run that many times. That solves the mystery! If you post your reply as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to try to gather evidence that would either confirm or refute the theory that you have a bad plan that is doing a Cartesian product.  Is `executions` in `v$sql` 1?  Or 36308?  If it is 1, that would support the Cartesian product theory and I would start looking for the query plan in `v$sql_plan` or `dba_hist_sql_plan` depending on when this happened and whether you are licensed to use the AWR.  If it is 36308, on the other hand, that would imply that the query is updating 36308 rows but something caused it to be called 36308 times because something is trying to loop over every row in the table.

Comment: Great answer! Helped pinpoint to the mystery. When the DBAs sent the top activity chart from the Grid control this morning, it looked like that one SQL was taking that long. Like you said, actually it's the cached SQL that kept running that many times during that 1+ hour. Just started looking at the problem this morning - missed that the outer loop was using the same table. Thanks for narrowing it down for me!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any particular reason for behavior you are describing here. Anyway, as a workaround, could you try with an alternate UPDATE, such as this:

```
UPDATE 
    (SELECT c_bill.reason_desc oldDesc, codes.description newDesc
     FROM c_bill INNER JOIN codes ON
         code.code_group = 'TRANSACTION_TYPE' AND 
         codes.code = c_bill.reason_code)
SET oldDesc = newDesc
```

Unfortunately, it is hard for me to actually try this statement on Oracle right now. I know that I have seen this kind of update before.

Comment: Thanks @Zoran for your suggestion. I tried it, it definitely adds the where condition it was lacking. But the SQL didn't do much better than the previous version. Based on Justin Cave's comment, I looked at executions and there it was executing 36308 times!! So, I think the SQL being inside a loop without where condition caused it to look like Cartesian product. I will post back my findings, after I test it.

Comment: Your question was very informative, I think we have all learned something from it.